# I don't understand how to choose a database in MySQL.(Error 1056)

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1046

```
CREATE TABLE User(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    names VARCHAR(100),
    aling VARCHAR(30),
    eye VARCHAR(30),
    hair VARCHAR(30),
    gender VARCHAR(30),
    apperences INT,
    year INT,
    universal VARCHAR(10)
)
```

everywhere I look, such an example is shown... and nowhere does it say how to choose a database. even with a direct request

> 21:42:26
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE User(
>    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
>    names VARCHAR(100),
>    aling VARCHAR(30),
>    eye VARCHAR(30),
>    hair VARCHAR(30),
>    gender VARCHAR(30),
>    apperences INT,
>    year INT,
>    universal VARCHAR(10)
> )
> ```
>
> Error Code: 1046. No database selected
> Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar.   0.000 sec

I expected that I would just write and everything would work, but no

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/use.html from query window. Also Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar seems starightforward what ui are you using and can you see the sidebar? Have you CREATED a database before attempting to create table?

Comment: Either set default database (USE statement, see above) or specify the database where the table must be created in: `CREATE TABLE MyDatabase.User( ..`

Comment: that's it, there are no problems. thanks for the link